# How to register resource providers using Azure fluent resource management?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api, azure-management

I'd like to fully automate my resource creation process. Unfortunately brand new subscriptions don't have a few resource providers registered by default. E.g. SQL.
That's easily solved as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#noregisteredproviderfound

However this only outlines methods using either manually using the portal or using Powershell.

I'm looking for a solution using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent`

It seems inconsistent that I wouldn't be able to do it using C#, but I can't seem to be able to find the functionality anywhere.

**How to register resource providers for a new subscription using Azure fluent resource management?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to register resource providers for a new subscription using Azure fluent resource management?

We could use the following function in the **[Azure fluent resource management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent)** to registry providers.

```
var result=resourceManagementClient.Providers.Register("provider name");
```

I also do a demo for it.

**Preparetion:**

[Registry Azure Active Directory application and assign Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application)

Then we can get the tenantId,clientId,clientSecretKey

**Steps:**

1.Create a C# console project and reference `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent`

2.Get accesstoken

```
 public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecretKey)
    {

        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecretKey);
        var tokenResponse = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        return accessToken;
    }
```

3. Initialize resourceManagementClient Object

```
TokenCredentials ccCredentials = new TokenCredentials(GetAccessToken(tenantId, appId, secretKey).Result);
            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(ccCredentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
```

4.Registry the resource provider

We also can list the unregistied providers

```
 var resources = resourceManagementClient.Providers.List().ToList(x => x.RegistrationState.Equals("NotRegistered"));

var result=resourceManagementClient.Providers.Register("provider name");
```

[image]

5.Check it from the Azure portal.

[image]

Code:

```
        static string appId = "Registried Azure AD Appliction Id";
        static string secretKey = "Client secret Key";
        static string tenantId = "tenant Id ";
        private static string subscriptionId = "subscription Id ";
        public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string azureTenantId, string azureAppId, string azureSecretKey)
        {

            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
            var tokenResponse = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TokenCredentials ccCredentials = new TokenCredentials(GetAccessToken(tenantId, appId, secretKey).Result);
            var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(ccCredentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
            var list1 = resourceManagementClient.Providers.List().ToList();
            var resource = resourceManagementClient.Providers.List().ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.NamespaceProperty.Equals("TrendMicro.DeepSecurity") && x.RegistrationState.Equals("NotRegistered"));
            var registry =resourceManagementClient.Providers.Register(resource?.NamespaceProperty);
        }
```

Packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provider Auto registration feature is added in the upcoming release of Azure Management SDK (Fluent) v. 1.1.