# Azure Management Libraries for .NET which is not dependant on .Net core

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

When looking for Azure Managment Libraries for .Net I came across 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent

but the prerequisite is it requires .Net Core. Is there a version which does not require such prerequisite.

I also came across https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/
but it looks old has not been updated since 2014.

**UPDATE:**

When I install Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent in regural console project 4.5 Framework. I get the below error

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent (≥ 1.0.0 && < 2.0.0)'. Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure (≥ 3.3.5 && < 4.0.0)'. Install-Package : 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'. At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

But when I install on a .Net Core Console project it installs without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have checked some release libraries from [Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent) as follows:

- [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/)

  Dependencies: .NETFramework 4.5, .NETStandard 1.3
- [Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent/)

  Dependencies: .NETFramework 4.5, .NETStandard 1.3

Also, I have checked with my console application target on .NET 4.5. In summary, you could use Azure Management Libraries with your project target on >= .NET 4.5 or >= .Net Core 1.0.

Comment: in the pre-requisit section https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent#pre-requisites it says .NET Core
Azure Service Principal - see how to create authentication info.

Comment: For authentication, I used `AzureCredentials` with a service principal registration before. Here is a similar issue about using Azure Management Libraries for .NET, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124221/how-to-register-resource-providers-using-azure-fluent-resource-management).

Comment: Any concerns when you use Azure Management Libraries for .NET, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: added more details above

Comment: I updated your question with your details. I just created an empty console application target on .NET 4.5, I could use this lib. From your detailed error, I assumed that there be multiple versions of `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure` reference, you need to check with your project.

Comment: I found something interesting. I have both VS2012 and VS2017 installed. When I install the package in VS2012 console application it throws error but when install package in VS2017 console application it installs fine both are using .net Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Have you tried to update your "NuGet Package Manager" for vs2012 ?

Comment: I think i have the latest NuGet Package Manager 2.8.60318.667

Comment: I am using vs 2015, I could not reproduce this issue. Are you creating a new project to test this issue in vs 2012 ? Or you could add your feedback for this package [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

Comment: Sure add it to the feedback. Yes I am creating a new VS2012 console project and the in NuGet Console I write Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent